Automatically separate a data without a delimiter into the designated column when I import a text file
I'm a beginner in using VBA in excel, my main problem is how can I automatically designate a data into the right columns when I import a file that I receive from one of our payment partners? They use comma as a delimiter but some of our consumers doesn't have a "First name" since they're registered as a business.
Here's an example of the text files they sent to us: 
As you can see, the data they generate uses comma as a delimiter. I don't have a problem when it's an individual account since they have a "First name".
Here's an example after I imported the text file into excel: The ones with the blue arrow are businesses.

Since it doesn't have a "First name", the data next to it proceeds to fill in the "first name" column.
so far here is my code when importing a file:
Sub ImportTextFile()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim qt As QueryTable
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set targetCell = ws.Range("A5")
    
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
    ws.Cells.Clear
    
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=targetCell)
    With qt
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub

Sub CreateButtonToImportTextFile()
    Dim btn As Button
    
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(100, 100, 100, 30)
    With btn
        .OnAction = "ImportTextFile"
        .Caption = "Import Text File"
    End With
End Sub


And this is my objective: 
Hoping I can get help and reccomendations!!

What about asking the creator of the file to give you a correct version of the file. One column is missing in the case of a business even if it is an empty column.

Unfortunately, they've given that responsibility to us since it's also a computer-generated data from them.  it's out of my control.

That is an excuse I would not accept from a payment partner. IMHO This is a mistake in the programm they are using to generate this file.

Anyway, I added two solution proposals.

I'll check it out and I'll let you know how it goes.

The third proposal to solve this would be to use PowerQuery instead.
The M-Code for the import
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("D:\tmp\CSV1\data.txt"), null, null, 1252)}),
    Step1 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "noOfCommas", each List.Count(Text.Split([Column1],","))-1),
    Step2 = Table.AddColumn(Step1, "Position", each Text.PositionOf([Column1],",",2){1}),
    Step3 = Table.AddColumn(Step2, "FixedCols", each if [noOfCommas]=4 then Text.ReplaceRange([Column1],[Position],1,",,") else [Column1]),
    Step4 = Table.SplitColumn(Step3, "FixedCols", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
    Step5 = Table.RemoveColumns(Step4,{"Column1", "noOfCommas", "Position"})
in
    Step5

Step1 determiness the number of commas in each line
Step2 determines the position of the second comma
Step3 adds a new column which either is the same as Column1 or in case of one comma too less it will add an extra comma on the postion determined in Step2. You have to adjust the number accordingly.
Step4 will split the newly created column by comma
Step5 will remove the first three columns which are not neccessary for the result

The PC my Company provided me doesn't support PowerQuery but I appreciate you for helping me! I hope this question would also help other people out. Thank you!

This code is restricted for this task only. (No parameters used). Call it before the End Sub statement of the ImportTextFile. It will insert a cell in column C in every row where the last cell of data (column J) is empty and moving to the right the cells on the right of it.
Sub insert_cell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set targetRange = ws.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
    
    For Each rw In targetRange.Rows
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rw.Row, "J")) Then
            ws.Cells(rw.Row, "C").Insert xlToRight
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub

To call
modify your sub like this: (insert one line)
Sub ImportTextFile()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim qt As QueryTable
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set targetCell = ws.Range("A5")
    
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
    ws.Cells.Clear
    
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=targetCell)
    With qt
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .Refresh
    End With

    ' call the cell inserter
    insert_cell         'line added 
End Sub


I've tried it, it runs but doesn't do anything. I have the same results.  I've inserted this code in L. 24 Col.5 What did I do wrong?

This is a subroutine as  ImportTextFile. Insert in the code module where the ImportTextFile sub is. To Call type before End Sub of ImportTextFile this: insert_cell

Why does it shows expected end sub?

It means End Sub is missing to close a Sub before either you start a new sub or it is the last sub in the module. Simply copy the three Subs in a module and click the generated button.

i have tried and it's still showing me the same result, help! lol

I finally got it, Thank you so much! appreciate you for helping out!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

One fix to the issue could be to import the file in a different way
Option Explicit

Function getTextfile(ByVal fileName As String) As String

    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim fileNr As Long
   
    fileNr = FreeFile
       
    Open fileName For Input As fileNr
    fileContent = Input(LOF(fileNr), fileNr)
    Close fileNr
   
    getTextfile = fileContent
End Function

Sub fixErrorInputfile()

    Const NoOfColumns = 6                   ' Adjust to the number of columns you have
    Const COMMA = ","                       ' Lines will be split by this character
    
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "d:\tmp\CSV1\data.txt"

    Dim fileContent As String
    fileContent = getTextfile(fileName)
    
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vLines As Variant
    vLines = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)

    Dim vData

    For i = LBound(vLines) To UBound(vLines)
        vData = Split(vLines(i), COMMA)
        If UBound(vData) = NoOfColumns - 1 Then         'vdata starts with 0
            col.Add vData
        ElseIf UBound(vData) = NoOfColumns - 2 Then     'assumption is that the only pitfall in the file missing 'First Name'
            ' add an empty column after last name
            ReDim Preserve vData(UBound(vData) + 1)
            Dim k As Long
            For k = UBound(vData) To LBound(vData) + 2 Step -1
                vData(k) = vData(k - 1)
            Next k
            vData(2) = ""
            col.Add vData
        End If
    
    Next i

    ' write out
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rg = rg.Resize(1, NoOfColumns)
    
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        rg.Value = col.Item(i)
        Set rg = rg.Offset(1)
    Next i
    
    
    
End Sub


Another way could be to correct the input file itself.
Option Explicit
Function getTextfile(ByVal fileName As String) As String

    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim fileNr As Long
   
    fileNr = FreeFile
       
    Open fileName For Input As fileNr
    fileContent = Input(LOF(fileNr), fileNr)
    Close fileNr
   
    getTextfile = fileContent
End Function
Function writeTextfile(ByVal fileName As String, fileContent As String) As String

    
    Dim fileNr As Long
   
    fileNr = FreeFile
       
    Open fileName For Output As fileNr
    Print #fileNr, fileContent
    Close fileNr
   
    'getTextfile = fileContent
End Function

Sub fixFile()

    Const NoOfColumns = 6                   ' Adjust to the number of columns you have
    Const COMMA = ","                       ' Lines will be split by this character
    
    Dim inFilename As String
    inFilename = "d:\tmp\CSV1\data.txt"

    Dim fileContent As String
    fileContent = getTextfile(inFilename)
    
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vLines As Variant
    vLines = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)

    Dim vData

    For i = LBound(vLines) To UBound(vLines)
        vData = Split(vLines(i), COMMA)
        If UBound(vData) = NoOfColumns - 1 Then         'vdata starts with 0
            col.Add vData
        ElseIf UBound(vData) = NoOfColumns - 2 Then     'assumption is that the only pitfall in the file missing 'First Name'
            ' add an empty column after last name
            ReDim Preserve vData(UBound(vData) + 1)
            Dim k As Long
            For k = UBound(vData) To LBound(vData) + 2 Step -1
                vData(k) = vData(k - 1)
            Next k
            vData(2) = ""
            col.Add vData
        End If
    
    Next i

    ' write out
    
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        vLines(i) = Join(col.Item(i), COMMA)
    Next i
    fileContent = Join(vLines, vbCrLf)
    
    Dim outFilename As String
    outFilename = "d:\tmp\CSV1\data1.txt"
    writeTextfile outFilename, fileContent
    
End Sub

